# DPDK: basicfwd example doesn't work onLinux Mint 21 running as a VM on VirtualBox

Tags: dpdk

I'm trying to run the basicfwd DPDK example under Linux Mint 21, running as a VM on VirtualBox.

I have the following 3 NICs:

verghis@verghis-VirtualBox:~/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/build$ ../usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status

## Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver

0000:00:08.0 '79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] 2000' drv=vfio-pci unused=pcnet32
0000:00:09.0 '79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] 2000' drv=vfio-pci unused=pcnet32

## Network devices using kernel driver

0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if=enp0s3 drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci *Active*

I've set up hugepages, but when I try to run the code I get the following error:

sudo examples/dpdk-skeleton -l 1 -n 4

verghis@verghis-VirtualBox:~/dpdk-stable-22.11.1/build$ sudo examples/dpdk-skeleton -l 1 -n 4
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 2
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
main() at line 192, file ../examples/skeleton/basicfwd.c, nb_ports 0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
Cause: Error: number of ports must be even

The 'number of ports' error is because it can't find even one port - why doesn't it find 2?

Thanks.

As above - happy to provide further details.

Comment: Turns out that the AMD 79c970 NIC isn't supported by DPDK, so I tried the Intel 82599, which is supported.  Only one NIC, but DPDK couldn't find it.  It's true that the basicfwd example wants an even number of NICs, but DPDK shoul have been able to find the single NIC.  Still looking into it, but I got it working with a pair of Intel 82540 NICs.